# Which way is better to map a string array and null check?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to map the result of adds to Codes?
`result.adds` contains a string array:
`string[] adds = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };`

Option 1:

```
    var car = new Car()
    {
        Name = request.Name,
        Codes = (result.adds != null) ? adds : new string[] { }
    };
```

In my opinion option 1 seems strange with creating a new empty string array when the result is false. I also have my doubts about mapping within the object mapping itself. On the other hand, it's direct and fast.

Option 2:

```
if (result.adds != null)
{
    adds = results.adds;
}

var car = new Car()
{
    Name = request.Name,
    Codes = adds
};
```

Option 2 null check seems overkill to define the code seperately. It could simply be included in the mapper.

Comment: that entirely depends on if `null` is a valid use-case for you, or if it´s really exceptional.

Comment: You can avoid creating new empty arrays by using `Array.Empty<string>()`.

Comment: _Option 2_ is not valid because `adds` is not initialized with any value if `result.adds == null`. I think the preferred solution should be `new Car { .. Codes = result.adds ?? Array.Empty<string>() }`.

Comment: Are you sure that _Option 1_ is valid? You check `result.adds` for NOT null and use another value. _Option 2_ is using the value of `result.adds` if it's not null - but there is no initializing of  `adds`.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann Maybe `adds` **is** initialized beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two options you've presented option #1 looks the cleanest. However, you can simplify it more if you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
var car = new Car()
{
    Name = request.Name,
    Codes = result.adds ?? Array.Empty<string>()
};
```

This will use an [empty string array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,bc9fd1be0e4f4e70) in `results.add` is null.

Comment: How on earth does this answer "is option 1 or 2 better"? You just provided another syntax for opt1.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Well, his question is phrased as both an opinion based question and one where he asks " What is the best way to map the result of adds to Codes"

Comment: and where is this "second" question **not** opiniated? Asside from that I doubt your answer really is the best, as "best" implies some ruleset we currently don´t know, which in this case is: is null even a valid value?